# I use windows 7 64 bit ,I just installed my IntelliJ IDEA and it hangs on the Select Home Directory for JDK

Tags: intellij-idea

Since I just installed IntelliJ , need to add a project SDK , any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds unlikely... Do you have multiple monitors or windows that cover the dialog?

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ Idea were you trying to install (12.1.5, or 13.xx) ? When you start IntelliJ do you use idea.exe or idea64.exe to launch it ? What happens if you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable and put java.exe in the PATH and then try to start Intellij? Which version of the JDK are you trying to use ?